# How can I update the stylesheet path with an onClick event?

Tags: reactjs

I import my styles at the header of the component:

`import "./styles.css";`

Now, how can I update the **Style Sheet** file path when I create an `onClick` event?

For example:

```js
<button onClick={changeFilePath}>Change Stylsheet Filepath</button>
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to add a class to a top-level dom element, is it possible that would solve your use-case instead of swapping out css files?

Comment: @MarkSwardstrom I'm going to have around 100 differents styles of a particular button so I think i'd be overkill to have that all in one file, right?